# Android OnClick not working on android 4.3

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-view

I have a fragment inside the main activity.The fragment contains an image view.My aim is to divide the image view into 3 different buttons.So ,i set up a linear layout which overlaps the image view and it contains 3 clickable views with equal gravity.

In the fragment i implements OnClickListener ,as this-

```
public class FragmentHomeMenu extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

View view;

Context activity_context;

View button_search_1;

View button_search_2;

View button_search_3;

...plenty of other stuff

public FragmentHomeMenu() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_menu, container, false);

    activity_context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    button_search_1 = (View) view
            .findViewById(R.id.button_search_1);
    button_search_1.setOnClickListener(this);

    button_search_2 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.button_search_2);
    button_search_2.setOnClickListener(this);


    button_search_3 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.button_search_3);
    button_search_3.setOnClickListener(this);
    ....plenty of other stuff

return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    activity_context = activity.getApplicationContext();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.w("", "some thing was clicked");
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_search_2:
        dostuff1();//stuff1 is not happening in android 4.3,but works on 4.0 
        break;
    case R.id.button_search_1:
        dostuff2();//stuff2 is not happening in android 4.3,but works on 4.0
        break;
    ......plenty of other stuff
}
```

I checked for the problem on plenty of places but could not find solution.My code works perfect on 
devices with android 4.0 but in 4.3 nothing happens when i click on the image.

here is the xml-

```
.......

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_searchbar"
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rltv1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/search_bar" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageview_searchbar"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageview_searchbar"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageview_searchbar"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageview_searchbar"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="21" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/button_search_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/button_search_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/button_search_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

.......lots of other stuff
```

Comment: i closest guess is that there is some problem with the context i pass ....may be that is handled differently in android 4.3.....still i don't know the exact proper way to pass it using fregments

Comment: Please try to use a attribute  - -     android:descendantFocusable="blockDescendants"

Comment: where should i use this attribute ....i used it on the linear layout ..... it didn't seam to work :/

Comment: Is it intentional that your second and third view have their height set to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`, as the first one has? They should have zero dp height then, making them unclickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out-I just had to bring the linear layout(containing buttons) to the front.
It got hidden under the image when using android 4.3 so i did this-

```
LinearLayout search_bar_buttons = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_search_bar_buttons);
    search_bar_buttons.bringToFront();
```

Thank you guys for helping